# How to fetch value from response body on python

Tags: python

Want to fetch two value from the response body(the response is html type). Which are `CSRF_NONCE` and `jsessionid`.

Response Body: (just copied the part of the response) which contain these two value and I have around total of 36 of `CSRF_NONCE` and `jsessionid` in my response and all are same. I want to select the first one.

```
<td class="row-left"><a href="/manager/html/list;jsessionid=A9B9660B7F3B1238FE0037843C225537?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=2AF805C8EF13A9B39258B056FF37136C">List Applications</a></td>
\n
<td class="row-center"><a href="/manager/../docs/html-manager-howto.html" rel="noopener noreferrer">HTML Manager Help</a></td>
\n
<td class="row-center"><a href="/manager/../docs/manager-howto.html" rel="noopener noreferrer">Manager Help</a></td>
\n
<td class="row-right"><a href="/manager/status;jsessionid=A9B9660B7F3B1238FE0037843C225537?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=2AF805C8EF13A9B39258B056FF37136C">Server Status</a></td>
```

Code Sample:

```
from jproperties import Properties
import requests
from autorizationModule import *

configs = Properties()
with open('app-config', 'rb') as config_file:
    configs.load(config_file)
#User Name & Password provide from the property file
TOKEN = authorization(configs.get("user_name").data, configs["password"].data)
print(f"Token Value", TOKEN)
def fetchCSRFNonce():
    BASE_URL =  configs.get("app_url").data
    payload = {}
    HEARDER_VALUE = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic "+str(TOKEN)
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=HEARDER_VALUE, data=payload)
    print(response.content)
fetchCSRFNonce()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need [an HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know about HTML parser, but can be done using the regular expression as well with few tweak to your code,

```
from jproperties import Properties
import requests
import re
from autorizationModule import *

configs = Properties()
with open('app-config', 'rb') as config_file:
    configs.load(config_file)


TOKEN = authorization(configs.get("user_name").data, configs["password"].data)
def fetchCSRFNonce():
    BASE_URL =  configs.get("app_url").data
    payload = {}
    HEARDER_VALUE = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic "+str(TOKEN)
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=HEARDER_VALUE, data=payload)
    html_response = response.content.decode()
   
    # Extract jsessionid
    jsessionid_match = re.search(r'jsessionid=([^"]*)\?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE', html_response)
    if jsessionid_match:
        JESSIONID_TOKEN = jsessionid_match.group(1)
    else:
        JESSIONID_TOKEN = None
   
    # Extract CSRF_NONCE
    csrf_nonce_match = re.search(r'org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=(.*?)"', html_response)
    if csrf_nonce_match:
        CSRFNONCE_TOKEN = csrf_nonce_match.group(1)
    else:
        CSRFNONCE_TOKEN = None

    print("JSESSIONID:", JESSIONID_TOKEN)
    print("CSRF_NONCE:", CSRFNONCE_TOKEN)
      
fetchCSRFNonce()
```